# How to remove all duplicates from json string

Tags: python, json

I have json that looks like this

```
{"k2": 39, "k1": 52}
{"k2": 39, "k1": 52}
{"k3": 66, "k2": 38}
{"k2": 35}
{}
{}
{"k1": 52, "k2": 39}
```

I need to delete all duplicated dicts from this json

I was trying to use set comprehension with tuple but it doesnt work i've got an error

```
'str' object has no attribute 'items'
```

code.py

```
import json

a = open('aboba.json', 'r')

data = a.read()

get_json = json.loads(json.dumps(data))



delete_all_dublicates = [dict(t) for t in {tuple(d.items()) for d in get_json}]

print(delete_all_dublicates)
```

Comment: why did you do `json.loads(json.dumps(data))`... because it made the `json.loads(data)` error go away? You undestand, it was erroring because you file **is not valid JSON*? You have newline delimited JSON though.

Comment: So the problem that i dont have ',' in my json?

Comment: `json.loads(json.dumps(data))` doesn't actually accomplish anything. The code would work the same if you replaced that with `data`, as in `get_json = data`. Since you're trying to read json, this indicates a problem. The json itself isn't valid. What you need is an array of objects but what you have is several objects concatenated together.

Comment: No. Just adding `,` won't make it valid JSON.

Comment: So how can i parse that?

Comment: You could read this line by line and parse each line individually, since this seems to be valid JSON lines format. But what is the **source** of this JSON? Note, someone clearly incorrectly believed that it was valid JSON, since the extension is JSON, so the source of that error should probably be fixed (at the very least, giving it the correct extension,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correct, by provided steps you can remove duplicates:

1. Split JSON data into individual JSON strings.
2. Convert each JSON string to a Python dictionary and sort it's keys
3. Use a set to keep track of unique dictionaries
4. Remove duplicates by adding sorted dictionaries to the set
5. Convert the tuples back to dictionaries
6. Convert the result list back to a JSON string

```python
import json

json_data = '''
    {"k2": 39, "k1": 52}
    {"k2": 39, "k1": 52}
    {"k3": 66, "k2": 38}
    {"k2": 35}
    {}
    {}
    {"k1": 52, "k2": 39}
'''

json_list = [json_str.strip() for json_str in json_data.split('\n') if json_str.strip()]

dict_list = [json.loads(json_str) for json_str in json_list]
sorted_dicts = [dict(sorted(d.items())) for d in dict_list]

unique_dicts = set()

unique_dicts = {tuple(d.items()) for d in sorted_dicts}

result = [dict(d) for d in unique_dicts]

result_json = '\n'.join(json.dumps(d) for d in result)

print(result_json)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my answer using the operator **:

```
json_data = '''{"k2": 39, "k1": 52}
{"k2": 39, "k1": 52}
{"k3": 66, "k2": 38}
{"k2": 35}
{}
{}
{"k1": 52, "k2": 39}'''

import json
dict_lst = [json.loads(d) for d in json_data.split("\n")]

d_all = dict()

for d in dict_lst:
    # ** turns the dictionary into keyword parameters:
    d_all = dict(d_all, **d)
    
d_all
# {'k2': 39, 'k1': 52, 'k3': 66}
```